# Android getTriggerTime different results in Android version 9.0

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-version

I just started to develop my Android app for alarm management and I discovered that `getTriggerTime()` (from `[AlarmManagement][1]` class offered by Android API)  returns different results in different Android versions.

Let's say I have code something like this:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
long alarmTime= am.getNextAlarmClock().getTriggerTime();
```

If `alarmTime` milliseconds are converted into date and time then in Android versions 5,6,8 it returns correct time and date of the alarm. However in version 9 it returns date and time 5 minutes prior to the real alarm time. 
Actually, I am not sure if version 9 is the problem or something is wrong with the three Samsung galaxy S9 phones I tested it on.

So now I don't  know what to do with my findings. Any advice? Do I have to treat this somehow in my code (if android version X than add + 5 minutes)? It sounds very unprofessional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is related to Samsung clock app. https://eu.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S9-S9/Pie-Clock-app-bug/td-p/927333

Comment: Thanks, at least now I know whats hapenning. I checked it again, and it still doesn't work.